# When i add an item the tableview is empty

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Edit: the last problem is solved by itachiUchiha but i have a new problem,
When i add an item the table view don't show it.
i add the initialize and de add method.
I do the app in 2 window. code in the window that i have a textfielsd to pass de date.

```
@FXML
private TextField esport;
@FXML
private TextField equips;
@FXML
private TextField despeses;
@FXML
private TextField esportistes;
@FXML
private TextField puntuacio;
@FXML
private TextField socis;
@FXML
private CheckBox festes;
@FXML
private CheckBox disiplina;
@FXML
private CheckBox voluntari;
@FXML
private CheckBox instalacions;
@FXML
private Button bafegir;
@FXML
private Button bcancelar;
Subvencio sub = new Subvencio();

 private void afegir(ActionEvent event) {
    //Passem els valors de el textfield als seus corresponents formats.
    int aux1 = Integer.parseInt(equips.getText());
    double aux2 = Double.parseDouble(despeses.getText());
    int aux3 = Integer.parseInt(esportistes.getText());
    int aux4 = Integer.parseInt(puntuacio.getText());
    int aux5 = Integer.parseInt(socis.getText());
    boolean aux6 = festes.isPressed();
    boolean aux7 = disiplina.isPressed();
    boolean aux8 = voluntari.isPressed();
    boolean aux9 = instalacions.isPressed();
    String aux10 = esport.getText();
    //Comprobem si tots els textfielsd estan omplits, sino es així, mostrem un error.
     if ((!equips.getText().isEmpty())
        && (equips.getText().trim().length()!=0)
        && (!despeses.getText().isEmpty())
        && (despeses.getText().trim().length()!=0)
            && (!esportistes.getText().isEmpty())
        && (esportistes.getText().trim().length()!=0)
            && (!puntuacio.getText().isEmpty())
        && (puntuacio.getText().trim().length()!=0)
            && (!socis.getText().isEmpty())
        && (socis.getText().trim().length()!=0)
            && (!esport.getText().isEmpty())
        && (esport.getText().trim().length()!=0))
     { 
       //Carregem un controllardor per poder crear subvencions i la creeem. en cabar aques proces la finestra es tanca.
       GeneralController aux = new GeneralController();
       aux.subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       sub.setEsport(aux10);
       sub.setEquips(aux1);
       sub.setEsportistes(aux3);
       sub.setFestes(aux6);
       sub.setFormacio(aux7);
       sub.setInstalacions(aux9);
       sub.setPuntuacio(aux4);
       sub.setSocis(aux5);
       sub.setVoluntari(aux8);
       sub.setdespeses(aux2);
       aux.subs.add(sub);
       Node minodo = (Node) event.getSource(); 
       minodo.getScene().getWindow().hide();
     }
     else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        //Apliquem el css cridant al metode dialogpane
        DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
        dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/estil/flatterfx.css").toExternalForm());
        dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("button");
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Error al afegir una subvenció.");
        alert.setContentText("Deus emplenar tots els cuadres de text per poder afegir una subvenció.");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

     }
}
```

code in button add that open de 2nd window.

```
private void afegir(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    //Carregem el controlador i inicialitzem la finestra a obrir.
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/model/Afegir.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage ventana2= new Stage();
    ventana2.setMinHeight(380);
    ventana2.setMinWidth(770);
    ventana2.setTitle("Afegir dades");
    ventana2.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ventana2.setScene(scene);
    //Fem que espere fins a ser tancada i coloquem els elements a la taula.subs = new ObservableList<Subvencio>();
    ventana2.showAndWait();
    tabla.setItems(subs);
}
```

and the initialize int de 1 window for set values in tableview and set items.

```
  */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ArrayList<Subvencio> misSubs = new ArrayList<Subvencio>();
    subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(misSubs);
    cesport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Subvencio, String>("Esport"));
    ctotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Subvencio, Double>("Subvenció"));
    tabla.setItems(subs);
}
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: To initialize an Observable list you need to make use of the util methods provided by FXCollections i.e. `subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

Comment: @ItachiUchihaThanks for helpthe error was solver but when i add an item the tableview don't show it. is empty always. Sorry for my english jeje

Comment: How do you add an item to the table?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i show us my code to initialize the tableview and the method add.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are re-initializing `aux.subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` in `afegir(ActionEvent event)`. The ObservableList used as items for TableView should be initialized just once and you can add/remove data from it.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i think that you stay in correct but if i don't put this line in the code teh program show me a nullpointerexception.That is the reason for my first post.

Comment: Just declare and initialize the ObservableList as a field. `public class Controller { ... ObservableList<String> subs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); ... }` and use it everywhere else. This way there will be no chance of a NPE.

Comment: This question is unanswerable as it stands. What classes are these two different `afegir(...)` methods defined in? What is the relationship of those classes? What is the `GeneralController` class that you instantiate in the first `afegir` method, and why would you expect the `subs` field in that instance to reference the table (which I think is what you are assuming). Please create a [MCVE] without any irrelevant material but which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also it's unclear whether there are appropriately named methods in the `Subvencio` class (see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview/7289/propertyvaluefactory#t=201608121438259535247 for naming conventions)